# JavaScript - Select all which have :not()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to call a variable within the `querySelectorAll()` Method. It doesn't work out.

```js
function _hide() {
  //Returns as string which corresponds exactly to the Class I want to store

  let _toShow = "." + document.getElementById("fb-select").value;

  //Should store a Nodelist which contains everything except the class to show

  let card = document.querySelectorAll('.card:not(_toShow)')

  //Hides the elements in the Nodelist
  card.forEach((card) => {
    card.style.scale = "0";
    card.style.opacity = "0";
  });
}
```

```css
/* need CSS here or might not */
```

```html
<div>need more HTML</div>
```

The Use case is to hide all Elements which have not a specific Class.
Thanks for advice.

Comment: I think you should use string literal or concat var  ```let card = document.querySelectorAll(`.card:not(${_toShow})`)
```

Comment: Perhaps a working example as a snippet - I created one to get you started

Comment: Can the contents of `fb-select` value be multiple words?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem was that you were presenting _toShow as a literal string instead of a variable. Try breaking it out with plus signs in the querySelectorAll func.

Another possible issue is that you weren't resetting the styles of previous cards before setting styles on the selected one(s). I used the colors red and black to demonstrate. Depending on what you're doing, this might not be applicable.

```js
function _hide() {

  //Returns as string which corresponds exactly to the Class I want to store
  let _toShow = "." + document.getElementById("fb-select").value;

  //Should store a Nodelist wich contains evrything except the class to show
  let cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card:not(' + _toShow + ')')

  let allCards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
  allCards.forEach((card) => {
    card.style.color = "black";
  });

  //Hides the elements in the Nodelist
  cards.forEach((card) => {
      card.style.color = "red";
  });
}

document.getElementById("fb-select").addEventListener("change", function(){
  _hide();
});

_hide();
```

```css
.cardCont{
 display: flex;
}

.card{
  border-radius:15px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 145px;
}
```

```html
<select id="fb-select">
  <option name="foo">foo</option>
  <option name="bar">bar</option>
  <option name="biz">biz</option>
</select>
<div class="cardCont">
<div class="foo card">Foo</div>
<div class="bar card">Bar</div>
<div class="biz card">Biz</div>
</div>
```